# How to get Product id from specific Product Catalog Rule?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, catalog-price-rules, widget

I created a widget which is a display product section for a specific catalog price rule selected by admin.

Ex: Admin select 20% off on pants from backend & '10' will be limit of displaying product on the frontend, it will display 10 products which is affected by that specific catalog price rule.

I am using custom SQL query to fetch product id as per catalog price rule, everting is working perfectly except SQL query also count child product as a parent product, I need to filter that.

Here is my block where I am getting product ids:

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\AbstractModel;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class Posts extends AbstractModel implements BlockInterface {

  public function myFunction(){
    //Getting the value of catalog rule id & number of limitations for the product.

    $myvalue = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('CustomSection/Customgroup/Customfield', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    $myvalue2 = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue('CustomSection/Customgroup/CustomSecondfield', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);

    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of object manager
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $tableName = $resource->getTableName('catalogrule_product'); //gives table name with prefix
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT `product_id` FROM ". $tableName." WHERE rule_id=".$myvalue." LIMIT ".$myvalue2;
    $results = $connection->fetchAll($sql);

    return $results;
  }
 protected $_template = "widget/posts.phtml";
}
```

currently, it's displaying 10 products which is similar like Parent Product and other 9 will be its child product which is different by color or size, etc

I appreciate if someone helps me to get product id collection by any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Model\Rule` to get a collection of products by catalog price rules.

I also used `Type\Configurable` to get product type, so the product can filter by parent or child.

```
   public function __construct(Context $context,
                              \Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule $rule,
                            \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable $catalogProductTypeConfigurable,
                            array $data = [])
{
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->_scopeConfig = $_scopeConfig;
    $this->rule = $rule;
    $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable = $catalogProductTypeConfigurable;
}

    public function myFunction(){
    $getRuleId //get catalog rule by scopeconfig
    $getProductLimit // get product limit by scopeconfig

    $results = $this->rule->load($getRuleId);
    $products = $results->getMatchingProductIds();
    $finalproducts = [];
    foreach ($products as $key=>$value){
        $parentByChild = $this->_catalogProductTypeConfigurable->getParentIdsByChild($key);
        if (isset($parentByChild[0]) && !in_array($parentByChild[0],$finalproducts)) {
            $finalproducts[] = $parentByChild[0];
        }
    }
    $output = array_slice($finalproducts, 0, $getProductLimit);
    return $output;
}
```